# Do not want the text to be centered

Tags: html, css, text, center, undo

i've never programmed before or anything, but i have a college project in which i have to edit a layout. 
there's a part of it in which the text is kinda in center, when it reaches the center of the page it skippes to next line.. i want it to continue normally.. 
https://jsfiddle.net/nqpa6jh0/#&togetherjs=vORwosTiHV

```css
.image.feature2 {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 0em 0;
}

.image.feature2 img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left
}

.image.feature3 img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: right;
```

```html
<div class="wrapper style2">
  <section class="container">
    <header class="major">
      <h2>Depoimentos</h2>
      <span class="byline">Os viajantes recomendam.</span>
    </header>
    <div class="row no-collapse-1">
      <section class="">
        <a class="image feature2"><img src="images/pic02.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <p>Nam in massa. Sed vel tellus. Curabitur sem urna, consequat vel, suscipit in, mattis placerat.</p>
      </section>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

here's how it's looking

[image]

that's how i wanted it to look like (photoshopped the first one):

[image]

Comment: Please create a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), [codepen](https://codepen.io/) or similar, for people to experiment with. Include a link to it in your question. Include everything needed for a working sample, even if it doesn't quite work, including the html, css, js and ***images***, as needed.

Comment: sorry didnt know. here it's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nqpa6jh0/#&togetherjs=vORwosTiHV

Comment: Are you using a framework or something?

Comment: i'm not sure.. sublime text

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain it properly to you.

From the photoshopped image, I can see what you are trying to achieve as well as the errors in your code. There are plenty of them.

Here: (redundant code)

```
.image.feature2 img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left
}

.image.feature3 img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: right;
}
```

You are not using classes properly. Classes are meant to remove the redundant code in css. Lets consider you added a class `myParentClass` to the div containing the sections as well remove the class <strike>image feature2</strike> on `a`  element.  Then the html would look like:

```
<div class="myParentClass row no-collapse-1">
  <section class="">
    <a ><img src="images/pic02.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <p>Nam in massa. Sed vel tellus. Curabitur sem urna, consequat vel, suscipit in, mattis placerat.</p>
  </section>
  <section class="">
    <a><img src="images/pic02.jpg" alt=""></a>
    <p>Nam in massa. Sed vel tellus. Curabitur sem urna, consequat vel, suscipit in, mattis placerat.</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

The above css can be replaced with:

```
.myClass section a img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left
}

.myParentClass section:nth-child(odd) a img {
  float: right;
}
```

And in order to make the text inside the `p` elements not to wrap around, you need to add  `white-space": nowrap`. So:

```
.myParentClass section p {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

And to have the effect of having some whitespace to the left of `odd` section elements, you must use `padding` i.e,

```
.myParentClass section:nth-child(odd){
  padding-left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: sorry, i dont get it the nth-child(odd).. i might be doing something wrong too because i added white-space": nowrap and it didnt do anything.. i must be doing something wrong i dont know

Comment: and this guy https://stackoverflow.com/a/51129526/10018813 seems to have fixed it.. but when i copy his code and paste here the text keeps same line. maybe thats something wrong with my computer..

Comment: No. There is nothing wrong with your computer. Maybe something is overwriting the rule. Just place it at the end of your css file, thus making it to override other rules if mistakenly defined.

Comment: didnt work.. i think i'm gonna switch templates, the footer background went missing too.. thanks